# Is far Infrared heaters in the market truly producing healthy far Infrared and is it practical to install them at home?

Tags: radiation, heat

I read few blogs and websites about far infrared heaters and all are very possible about this new technology. I bought one of the heaters as a test and find quite impressive also.

However, I am concern about long term health effect. I know, there is no health effect of far infrared but the Heater that is producing infrared, is it truly producing only far infrared?

This business is not regulated so What Type of test (or certificate) the heater has to pass before coming in the market?

I am planning to install this heaters in my whole apartment, anyone has experience to live in a flat/house with far infrared heater? if then can you please share your experience? Is it medically healthy?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far infrared is also known as thermal radiation. It is less harmful to the human body than red light and blue light. If you are under a cloudy sky and it is hot, say 30 degrees, that is how harmful thermal radiation is to the body.

The hight you climb up the electromagnetic spectrum, from radio waves to thermal waves to light waves to UV Xrays and Gamma rays, the more they can interfere with atoms and molecules, because they can disrupt bonds, ionize, and so forth.

So IR can only heat the body and can't ionize or disrupt the body.

Far infrared is the heat you feel when you are far away from a fire and the heat travels towards you without air transport. Near infrared is the heat you feel closer to the radiator, and that which causes convection nearest to the heat source, it gets absorbed faster by the air.

Insulation is most important for heating, as more than 50 percent of heating is lost through the ceiling. modern buildings in the west have high roof insulation standards.

oil heaters tend to absorb near infrared and reflect it back as far infrared better.

I think that the smaller and hotter the source, the nearer thermal wavs it produces, and the larger and less hot surfaces can make more far infrared.

It sounds like a lot of marketing terms.

Oil heaters are traditionally very efficient. I had one which i bought a bit rusty for 15 euros and it has lasted 5 years. the only issue with oil heaters is that they can eventually leak when very worn or less strongly welded.

microwaves are less HF than thermal, and they have not been associated with any health risks either even from phones used all day beside the ear.

You can think of far infrared as the warmth that is reflected from a hot wall heated by the sun. It is one of the least dangerous forms of radiation.

you may consider investing in a HPS lamp of 600 or 1000w because it produces 90 percent heat from that, and also vast amounts of light which are good for mental biology and good for growing tomatos and strawberries in the middle of winter. because they go in a ventilated area under a table in the house, the also radiate well. of all kinds of radiators, i prefer by far sitting under a hot lamp with a summer hat tending plants in the middle of winter, it's definitely hot. A 600W lamp can produce about 200 tomatos, 100 strawberries and 20 peppers and some melons/beans etc, in the winter months.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful reply. I am not using far infrared heater outside though. I will use inside in my house to get heat in this coming winter. more or less 16 hours i will get heat from these heaters. I am a small child. My main concern is on her health. These heaters are cheap and feels comfortable. just i am concert about longer term effect. In UK I haven't seen any far infrared heating system. I wonder why?

Comment: hot tea is also full of radiation. so how is an IR heater made... some electricity passes through some flat metal zigzags of a larger surface area than a normal heat and the heat is therefore lower on a larger surface. that's all it is. you generate far infrared inside your own body, about 50W of it. it is radiation because you emit heat. it's safe, probably better than a cheaper heater, both are safer for your child than pesticides on fruit, factory foods and excessive cleanliness, none of which are healthy, 100 degrees radiators are as healthy as standing beside a hot pan of water.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using FI heater now and feel really comfortable at home and cheaper heating.